# Access child record created from a sublist on the parent

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, before-save, user-event

I have a locked bundle and I am unable to trigger a beforesubmit script on the ‘create’ instance of one of the records. I was told that this record is created as a child record from a sublist on the parent record(without using record.create). When you create records using this functionality, the User Events of the created Child record are not triggered.
Is there any alternative options for this issue? I need to make some changes to a field on create of the new record.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the user event on the child record instead ?

Let me know if this way works for you

Comment: The script is deployed on the child record, but it does not trigger on new record creation.

Comment: The other more extreme case , would be to have a client script , and on validate line or validateInsert either trigger a suitelet and do stuff on the current record , or task a workflow action .the line would be the sublist line this child record is inserted